# Problemas ao fazer push para repositório remoto (GitHub)

Tags: git, github

Estou tendo uma dificuldade muito grande para colocar um projeto no *GitHub*. Primeiro, quando tento fazer o *push* via ssh aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: printscreen do erro]

Depois, para tentar fugir do erro, tentei fazer via *HTTPS* e a mensagem apresentada foi a seguinte:

[image: printscreen do erro com o protocolo HTTPS]

Recriei as pastas com projeto, criei repositórios novos e já reconfigurei o usuário *git*. Não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: Esse repositório você criou? Ou outras pessoas estão usando?

Comment: Eu criei. Não há ninguém mais usando.

Comment: Tente configurar a chave estrangeira para conseguir o acesso, veja ==> [aqui](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/)

Comment: Você tem que adicionar uma nova chave SSH à sua conta do GitHub. help github:
https://help.github.com/pt/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa gerar sua chave publica e privada com o seu usuário(não como root) digite no terminal

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "seuemail@example.com"
```

com esse comando sera gerado o seu par de chaves, no diretório ~/.ssh depois que as chaves estiverem geradas entre no seu github clique na sua foto do perfil e clique no item Settings na pagina que abrir no lado direito terá um menu com o item [SSH and GPG keys](https://github.com/settings/keys) clique nele e na tela que abrir clique em "New SSH Key" abrira uma tela com dois campos Title e Key no title você pode colocar um titulo que vá identificar a chave por exemplo Chave notbook, chave do trabalho etc.. no campo key você deve copiar o conteúdo da sua chave publica, entre no terminal com seu usuário

```
cd ~/.ssh
cat id_rsa.pub
```

o comando cat vai imprimir a chave no terminal copie todo o o conteúdo e cole no campo key depois clique em "Add SSH Key" apos fazer isso você deve conseguir usar o repositório ssh sem problemas